# Android Studio 2.1 layout preview not working from template

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, preview

I have created a project in Android Studio 2.1 from the Navigation Drawer template.  I made no changes to the project files but only one XML layout will show in the Preview: nav_header_main.xml.

The other layouts, activity_main.xml, app_bar_main.xml, content_main.xml all show this:
[image: screenshot]

Shouldn't the built-in templates work out of the box?  What setting am I missing?

Comment: By the way, this problem goes away when I render it for API 23.  But I need to work towards API 21 or 22.